# Future tense of verbs

Tags: will-be-going

When someone asks me, for example, to go with him to the cinema and I want to reply that I can't because I have to go to the doctor's, what should I say?

> 1. *I'm visiting a doctor*
> 2. *I'm going to visit a doctor*
> 3. *I will visit a doctor*..

My question is when we should use

- *be going to*
- *be* + present continuous
- *Will* ?

Which one is the most correct option in the provided context?

Comment: Don't use *will*. (And use *see*, not *visit*.) The other two are fine.

Comment: You could use "will" if you say _I will be seeing a doctor [at that time]._

Comment: First, _I will_ is almost always contracted to _I'll_ in speech. What I would say in the context is what you said: "I can't because I have to go to the doctor's". That's the most natural in that context. Since you're talking about a future event (doctor visit) simultaneous with another future event (movie), you wouldn't use any of (1-3); they are for independent events. This is a place where the continuous can be handy. When the movie happens, you will be unavailable, so you can say _I'll be seeing the doctor then_ or _I'll be at the doctor's then_. No need to be overprecise.